# How do you force an asp:Panel to overflow to the right when dynamically adding controls to a web site?

Tags: asp.net, css, web

I'm trying to dynamically add controls to an asp:Panel on a web site so that they all appear on the same line. I have a set width, but when I add overflow:auto they still continue to be added on the next line when they run out of space. Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: I think I need something like the flowLayoutPanel for windows forms

Comment: When discussing visual and layout issues with ASP.NET, please show the actual rendered HTML rather than talking about Controls.

Comment: Also, in addition to @Dai, my guess is that you need to concentrate on how to design CSS structure, and maybe HTML. It's a little bit difficult to see what you'd like to achieve and what the problem you get stuck on. We can guess but we also can ask (guess which is easier for us)...

Answer (score 0):

Are your controls based on panel controls?  Then this is normal behavior.  Panels are usually generated as <div/> tags, and <div/> tags start on a new line by default.

Without actual HTML as a base I can't give you example code, but I suspect in order to do what you want, you're going to have to explore the `display` attribute in CSS.  You can find out more about that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).